# C++ Expanding a dynamic array and deleting a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, delete-operator

I know I don't have all of the code here, but here is a bulk of code that throws an error when I run my client. Basically, it doesn't like my

```
delete[] oldList;
```

and I'm not too sure why. Here is the code block, thank you in advance for any comments. Ask if you need more from me, I'm just trying to figure out if I'm using pointers wrong. Thanks!

```
void OrdListClass::Expand()
{
    int tempLength = 0;

    ItemType* oldList = GetListPtr();

    ItemType* newList;

    SetSize(EXPANSION_FACTOR * GetSize());

    newList = new ItemType[GetSize()];

    SetListPtr(newList);

    for (int i = 0; i < GetLength(); i++)
    {

        newList[i] = oldList[i];
        tempLength = tempLength++;

    }

    SetLength(tempLength);

    delete[] oldList;

    oldList = NULL;

} // end Expand
```

edit 1:
The error only shows up if you run without debugging. If i debug, it doesn't ever throw a break on me. it happens on the line with "delete[] oldList;" if i ask it where it broke when i run without debugging. 
I realize I can just set the length at the end, I'm not worried about that so much. I'm curious why the program breaks if I try to delete the pointer. Thank you!

edit 2:
It seems that I'm a dummy and was debugging in VS13 wrong. When I try to insert into my list, if there's a duplicate key then it throws an exception (DuplicateInsertException()). Are exceptions that I throw supposed to stop my program?

Comment: what error it throws?

Comment: `tempLength = tempLength++;` is undefined behavior. Why not simply `tempLenth++;`? (Or better, don't touch that in the loop and just set it at the end.)

Comment: `tempLength = tempLength++;` is rubbish.

Comment: @AliKazmi updated the post
I'm just looking to see if I'm using pointers wrong, I understand the tempLength is over complicating something simple. Thanks!!

Comment: @SiggyxLeGiiT: it's not just overcomplicating. It is _undefined behavior_ (look it up). Simply put, that line is invalid C++. It can produce any result at all.

Comment: @Mat Oh okay. I've fixed it up, to where it's just "tempLength++;" now.

Comment: Are you using `new` with an array syntax? My guess is that you are not.

Comment: @RSahu Looking back, I think I've been looking in the wrong place. My insert method is throwing an exception. check the edit #2

Comment: "Are exceptions that I throw supposed to stop my program?" - if you don't catch them. *yes*.